# How to share the Folder to particular BU

Tags: marketing-cloud

[image]i want to share the Folder to  particular Business Unit in My account but i am not able to see same folder in another Business Unit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create your folder under Shared Items >> Shared Data Extensions
And then you can set its permissions. Hope that helps.

[image]

A silly thing about SFMC is that any folder that you create will get exposed in all the business units by default. You'll have to every time go and remove that access.  Once you click on permissions, you need to select the Business Unit from which you need hide and then uncheck all the boxes and just Save it.

[image]

Comment: i did that but its showing in other business also

Comment: i have click the permission then i gave access  to particular bu  but its showing in all business unit

Comment: how to remove the full access for business unit as i mention above diagram see this

Comment: I updated my answer. Please mark it correct if that solves your problem

Comment: my question is  remove the Full access permission for particular Business Unit

Comment: Yes as I explained, go to permissions.. select the BU checkbox .. click on edit permissions and uncheck all the boxes there and Save

Comment: i did as you said but not working its showing in all business units